# Jquery add class when section isVisible or Hidden on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

looking for suggestion on how to approach.

Div1 or section     -   If div 1 is visible on screen apply style 1

Div2 or section     -   If div 2 is visible on screen apply style 1

Div3 or section     -   If div 2 is hidden from screen apply style 2 or class 2

Div4 or section     -   If div 3 is hidden from screen  apply style 1 or class1

Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: What does "isVisible" or "Hidden from screen" mean to you? Not displayed, not scrolled into view, what?

Comment: Akash please show us what you have tried. Keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: I am working on the idea  with intersection observer, will share the whole implementation as I progress. . I wouldn’t want to use any sharing platform as coding service . Apologies if my question comes across as a coding service requirement.

Comment: I found the technical term intersection observer  to query visible or invisible section on screen . I believe that should solve the logic I am trying to achieve .

Answer (score 1):

Idea was to find about out the functions  available in JavaScript .

On researching more about the topic I found the intersection observer. Which seems like a brilliant options and faster load times.

Below is the the idea of implementatio, any suggestions  to improve would be great.

I considering to extend the script to use data attributes to have more control over the sections.

I am bit of a noob with JavaScript, Just trying to challenge my design with UX  scripting.

```js
//const primary = document.querySelector('.primary');
//const secondary = document.querySelector('.secondary');

const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.secondary');
const options = {
 root: null, //it is the viewport
 threshold: 0.25,
 rootMargin: '-15% 0%  -15% 0% ',
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(function (entries, observerer) {
 entries.forEach((entry) => {
  //console.log(entry.target);
  //entry.target.classList.toggle('inverse');
  if (entry.isIntersecting) {
   document.body.classList.toggle('inverse');
  }
 });
}, options);

sections.forEach((section) => {
 observer.observe(section);
});
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
section {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100vh;
 transition: background-color 1s ease;

 border: 1px solid;
}

:root {
 --primary: #f4f4f4;
 --secondary: #191918;
 --accent: #f9cdcd;
}

body {
 background-color: var(--primary);
 color: var(--secondary);
 transition: background-color 1s ease, color 1s ease;
 will-change: background-color, color;
}
h1 {
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 50px;
 font-size: 4rem;
}

.primary {
 display: inline-block;
}

.secondary {
 display: inline-block;
}

.accent {
 display: inline-block;
}

.inverse {
 background-color: var(--secondary);
 color: var(--accent);
 transition: background-color 1s ease, color 1s ease;
 will-change: background-color, color;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>IntersectionObserver</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./intersection_observer.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <section class="primary">
   <h1>Section 1</h1>
   <p>
    Deserunt tempor deserunt ullamco sunt eiusmod incididunt incididunt quis ea pariatur veniam pariatur
    duis in. Eu exercitation mollit irure ea velit cillum adipisicing laborum eu Lorem. Lorem elit voluptate
    non dolor. Quis veniam quis duis sint irure. Lorem laborum officia voluptate eiusmod quis esse quis elit
    quis est cupidatat ullamco elit nostrud. Sunt nisi aliqua incididunt commodo velit magna laboris.
   </p>
   <br />
   <p>
    Minim quis esse esse culpa. Commodo sunt ullamco deserunt consequat deserunt duis commodo irure
    consequat proident. Exercitation laborum commodo nostrud irure consectetur fugiat sit anim ex sint. Sit
    proident in est ullamco.
   </p>
   <br />
   <p>
    Veniam dolor in Lorem cupidatat nisi. Ad nulla id enim consectetur velit nulla ipsum culpa anim et
    consequat id pariatur do. Consequat eu irure excepteur commodo. Voluptate id fugiat aliqua sit do nisi
    id cupidatat tempor quis. Deserunt Lorem velit exercitation cupidatat non aliqua eiusmod magna eiusmod.
    Ipsum excepteur consectetur ea voluptate sunt. Non Lorem tempor dolore tempor amet laboris ad duis
    labore.
   </p>
  </section>
  <section class="secondary">
   <h1>Section 2</h1>
   <p>
    Deserunt tempor deserunt ullamco sunt eiusmod incididunt incididunt quis ea pariatur veniam pariatur
    duis in. Eu exercitation mollit irure ea velit cillum adipisicing laborum eu Lorem. Lorem elit voluptate
    non dolor. Quis veniam quis duis sint irure. Lorem laborum officia voluptate eiusmod quis esse quis elit
    quis est cupidatat ullamco elit nostrud. Sunt nisi aliqua incididunt commodo velit magna laboris.
   </p>
   <br />
   <p>
    Minim quis esse esse culpa. Commodo sunt ullamco deserunt consequat deserunt duis commodo irure
    consequat proident. Exercitation laborum commodo nostrud irure consectetur fugiat sit anim ex sint. Sit
    proident in est ullamco.
   </p>
   <br />
   <p>
    Veniam dolor in Lorem cupidatat nisi. Ad nulla id enim consectetur velit nulla ipsum culpa anim et
    consequat id pariatur do. Consequat eu irure excepteur commodo. Voluptate id fugiat aliqua sit do nisi
    id cupidatat tempor quis. Deserunt Lorem velit exercitation cupidatat non aliqua eiusmod magna eiusmod.
    Ipsum excepteur consectetur ea voluptate sunt. Non Lorem tempor dolore tempor amet laboris ad duis
    labore.
   </p>
  </section>
  <section class="primary">
   <h1>Section 3</h1>
   <p>
    Deserunt tempor deserunt ullamco sunt eiusmod incididunt incididunt quis ea pariatur veniam pariatur
    duis in. Eu exercitation mollit irure ea velit cillum adipisicing laborum eu Lorem. Lorem elit voluptate
    non dolor. Quis veniam quis duis sint irure. Lorem laborum officia voluptate eiusmod quis esse quis elit
    quis est cupidatat ullamco elit nostrud. Sunt nisi aliqua incididunt commodo velit magna laboris.
   </p>
   <br />
   <p>
    Minim quis esse esse culpa. Commodo sunt ullamco deserunt consequat deserunt duis commodo irure
    consequat proident. Exercitation laborum commodo nostrud irure consectetur fugiat sit anim ex sint. Sit
    proident in est ullamco.
   </p>
   <br />
   <p>
    Veniam dolor in Lorem cupidatat nisi. Ad nulla id enim consectetur velit nulla ipsum culpa anim et
    consequat id pariatur do. Consequat eu irure excepteur commodo. Voluptate id fugiat aliqua sit do nisi
    id cupidatat tempor quis. Deserunt Lorem velit exercitation cupidatat non aliqua eiusmod magna eiusmod.
    Ipsum excepteur consectetur ea voluptate sunt. Non Lorem tempor dolore tempor amet laboris ad duis
    labore.
   </p>
  </section>
  <section class="secondary">
   <h1>Section 4</h1>
   <p>
    Deserunt tempor deserunt ullamco sunt eiusmod incididunt incididunt quis ea pariatur veniam pariatur
    duis in. Eu exercitation mollit irure ea velit cillum adipisicing laborum eu Lorem. Lorem elit voluptate
    non dolor. Quis veniam quis duis sint irure. Lorem laborum officia voluptate eiusmod quis esse quis elit
    quis est cupidatat ullamco elit nostrud. Sunt nisi aliqua incididunt commodo velit magna laboris.
   </p>
   <br />
   <p>
    Minim quis esse esse culpa. Commodo sunt ullamco deserunt consequat deserunt duis commodo irure
    consequat proident. Exercitation laborum commodo nostrud irure consectetur fugiat sit anim ex sint. Sit
    proident in est ullamco.
   </p>
   <br />
   <p>
    Veniam dolor in Lorem cupidatat nisi. Ad nulla id enim consectetur velit nulla ipsum culpa anim et
    consequat id pariatur do. Consequat eu irure excepteur commodo. Voluptate id fugiat aliqua sit do nisi
    id cupidatat tempor quis. Deserunt Lorem velit exercitation cupidatat non aliqua eiusmod magna eiusmod.
    Ipsum excepteur consectetur ea voluptate sunt. Non Lorem tempor dolore tempor amet laboris ad duis
    labore.
   </p>
  </section>
  <script src="./intersectionobserver.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Ak